# scalar() argument 1 must be numpy.dtype error

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I am using a pickle file which just holds some hyperparameters, when I try loading the pickle file I get the following error:

```
 saved_args = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: scalar() argument 1 must be numpy.dtype, not numpy.dtype
```

can someone help me figure this error out?

Comment: Can you provide an exact minimal example of the actual code that causes the error?

Comment: How did you create the pickle file? When did you create it? Did you use the same python installation and the same numpy version which you are using to read it?

Comment: I am using [this](https://github.com/quancore/social-lstm) repo in the [file](https://github.com/quancore/social-lstm/blob/master/train.py) line number 146 creates the config file and I read it using [test](https://github.com/quancore/social-lstm/blob/master/test.py) line number 86. When I use it on windows with numpy=1.16.2 it generates this error but when I use it on Linux with numpy=1.16 it works well.